# Swift user defaults - array

Tags: arrays, swift, userdefaults

Getting error on the below code as

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String]?'
>   and 'String'

```
    func loadDefaults() {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? [String]
    if (userDefaults == "") || userDefaults != nil{
        persons = userDefaults!
    }else{
        persons = [""]
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't directly relevant to your question, but using the variable name `userDefaults` to contain a value you _read_ from UserDefaults is truly awful.

Comment: You are trying to compare an optional string array with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a dedicated method `array(forKey` to retrieve an array.

An empty array `isEmpty`, you cannot compare it with an empty `String`

If you want to load the stored array or assign an empty array if the object can't be found use

```
func loadDefaults() {
    // a variable name userDefaults for the array is confusing
    if let storedArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storedArray") as? [String] {
        persons = storedArray
    } else {
        persons = []
    }
}
```

or shorter

```
func loadDefaults() {
    persons = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storedArray") as? [String] ?? []
}
```

Comment: Note that this code is functionally equivalent to `persons = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "storedArray") ?? []`

Answer (score 1):

In your code `userDefaults` is of type `[String]?` and not `String` to be be campared to `""`. Binary operator `==` can only be used between two instances of the **same** type (This type has to adopt the Equatable protocol to use `==`).

You may use this snippet to check that `userDefaults` is not `nil` :

```
if let defaults = userDefaults {
    persons = defaults
} else {
    persons = [""]
}
```

Or with the guard statement :

```
guard let defaults = userDefaults else {
    persons = [""]
    return
}
persons = defaults
```

Your final function would look like this:

```
func loadDefaults() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? [String]
    if let defaults = userDefaults {
        persons = defaults
    } else {
        persons = [""]
    }
}
```

Or :

```
func loadDefaults() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? [String]
    guard let defaults = userDefaults else {
        persons = [""]
        return
    }
    persons = defaults
}
```

**P.S:** `persons = [""]` means that the `persons` would contain one element, that is `""`. If you want an empty array use this: `persons = []`

Comment: Works! Solved the issue

Comment: @Sureshtrb Glad I could help