# Storing arrays of string persistently in SwiftUI using AppStorage

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, userdefaults, appstorage

I'm trying to store an array of string in user defaults using the AppStorage property wrapper like this:

```swift
@AppStorage("History") var history: [String] = ["End of history"]
```

however I get the error `No exact matches in call to initializer`

Is this a limitation of AppStorage because UserDefaults can store arrays if I'm not wrong? What is a workaround I can use?

Comment: AppStorage does not have initializers for containers, only for simple concrete types supported by UserDefaults. So if you need to pack array then you need to encode/decode that manually (say to Data) or use custom property wrapper around UserDefaults as before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273624/swift-user-defaults-array