# Swift/SwiftUI: Using AppStorage to hold list of IDs

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to use `AppStorage` to hold a list of `id`'s for my `Country` struct.  I want to persist this list of `id`'s as favorites for a user and if it's a favorite, have the heart next to each country filled.
If they tap the heart to unfavorite it, it will remove the `id` from the `favLists` and if they tap it to favorite it, it will add it to the list.
This is not working as I expect and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
struct Number: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var countries: [Country]
    @Namespace var namespace;
    @AppStorage("favLists") var favLists: [Number] = [];
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { bounds in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(Array(filteredCountries.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,country) in
                        LazyVStack {
                            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                                HStack {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: CountryView(country: country),
                                        label: {
                                            HStack {
                                                Image(country.image)
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                Text(country.display_name)
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                                    .padding(.leading)
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                            .padding(.top, 12.0)
                                            
                                        }
                                    ).buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())
                                    if (favLists.filter{$0.id == country.id}.count > 0) {
                                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
                                            let index = favLists.firstIndex{ $0.id == country.id}
                                            if let index = index {
                                                favLists.remove(at: index)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "heart").foregroundColor(.red).onTapGesture {
                                            favLists.append(Number(id: country.id))
                                        }
                                        .padding(.top, 12)
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal, 16.0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: bounds.size.width)
                .navigationTitle("Countries")
                .font(Font.custom("Avenir-Book", size: 28))
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: it seems to be adding to the array when I log it but the image will `fill` properly but never unfill when I unfavorite it

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think `AppStorage` does not have initialiser for arrays (as you found-out it does not compile). You need to encode/decode your array to something, eg. `Data` or `JSON` by yourself. In your case, you are probably better-off using the "normal" UserDefaults. See:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273624/swift-user-defaults-array